# Passing Date through URL to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker, microsoft-edge

I currently have in progress a site that uses the bootstrap-datepicker. When a user changes the date, I'm using javascript to pass the date through a URL, and load the page in another container. Currently this is working in Chrome and Firefox correctly, however it's not working in IE. This is due to how the URL seems to be formated and being sent.

On the PHP page the code to get the date and format it is:

```
$day = strtotime($_GET['seldate']);
```

The Javascript is:

```
var selectedDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString();
```

On Chrome and Firefox it works correctly, and the URL is selDate=mm/dd/yyyy format. When it is printed out in IE, it shows ?10?/?10?/?2015

Also, when using encodeURIComponent on selectedDate. It decodes correctly to mm/dd/yyyy... but for some reason fails on the strtotime() call. I wonder if there's some hidden or mis translated character causing it to fail on the Edge browser, since that's where it's failing.

Comment: change format. 10-10-2015

Comment: How can I change it at the JS end?

Comment: read up on url encoding or use a different format

Comment: I just noticed that it actually is only occuring in the Edge browser mode of IE.

Answer (score 0):

$('#datepicker').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );

SOmething like that if you are using the UI datepicker.